# One well-known property of resultant

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=a_0(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ ,  $g(x)=b_0(x-b_1)\cdots(x-b_m)$

How to prove that $\operatorname{Res}(f,g)=a_0^mb_0^n\prod\limits_{i,j}{(a_i-b_j)}$?

I know. it's a well known fact, but all proves i met had one disadvantage: they prove this equality only in the case that all roots are different.

How to prove it in general case?

Comment: First prove it in a ring where the $a_i$ and $b_j$ are different indeterminates, then substitute.

Comment: You can take that formula as the definition of the resultant. What definition of the resultant are you starting from?

Comment: If you start from the Sylvester determinant, it's stated as Theorem 1.6 in http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN5.pdf and proved a few pages later.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments, see the proof at [this](http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN5.pdf) site. The author explicitly states that no assumption about distinct roots is made.